# Count the number of subsequent rows with the same value as the value in the first row

Tags: sql, count, sql-server-2016

I have the following base table:

```
+------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|    date    | CHFUSD | CHFJPY | CHFEUR | CHFGBP |
+------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| 24/03/2019 | 1.0016 | 0.009  | 1.1349 | 1.3327 |
| 23/03/2019 | 1.0016 | 0.009  | 1.1349 | 1.3327 |
| 22/03/2019 | 1.0016 | 0.009  | 1.1349 | 1.3209 |
| 21/03/2019 | 1.0016 | 0.0089 | 1.1349 | 1.3209 |
| 20/03/2019 | 1.0016 | 0.0089 | 1.1348 | 1.3209 |
| 19/03/2019 | 1.0016 | 0.0089 | 1.1348 | 1.3209 |
| 18/03/2019 | 0.998  | 0.0089 | 1.1359 | 1.3209 |
| 17/03/2019 | 1.0016 | 0.009  | 1.1349 | 1.3327 |
| 16/03/2019 | 1.0035 | 0.009  | 1.1348 | 1.3303 |
| 15/03/2019 | 0.998  | 0.0089 | 1.1359 | 1.3209 |
| 14/03/2019 | 0.998  | 0.0089 | 1.1359 | 1.3209 |
| 13/03/2019 | 0.998  | 0.0089 | 1.1359 | 1.3209 |
+------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Those are foreign exchange rates that show the daily rate for four currency pairs. I am now looking for a way to check how many days in a row, the same exchange rate was delivered.

The output of the query should look like this:

```
+------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|    date    | CHFUSD | CHFJPY | CHFEUR | CHFGBP |
+------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| 24/03/2019 |      6 |      3 |      4 |      2 |
+------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

The date is not a necessary column if it would complicate the exercise. Anyone with an idea on how to get this done? I was thinking about a window function that compares the value to the previous value and returns 0/1 based on that. Then a query on top where it sums the value for the rows that fit a criteria: date >= first date with value 0 (for each column).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a group-and-islands query -- but made more complicated because you have multiple columns to deal with.

I would recommend the difference of a row number and date to define the group.  Then a window function to get the values:

```
select t.*,
       count(*) over (partition by chfusd, dateadd(day, - seqnum_chfusd, date)) as cnt_usd,
       count(*) over (partition by chfjpy, dateadd(day, - seqnum_chfjpy, date)) as cnt_jpy,
       count(*) over (partition by chfeur, dateadd(day, - seqnum_chfeur, date)) as cnt_eur,
       count(*) over (partition by chfgbp, dateadd(day, - seqnum_chgbp, date)) as cnt_gbp
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by chfusd order by date) as seqnum_chfusd,
             row_number() over (partition by chfjpy order by date) as seqnum_chfjpy,
             row_number() over (partition by chfeur order by date) as seqnum_chfeur,
             row_number() over (partition by chfgbp order by date) as seqnum_chfgbp
      from t
     ) t;
```

If you want this for the most recent date, then add `select top (1)` and `order by date desc`.  For another date, use a subquery.

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot, it works (had to correct a few spelling mistakes, e.g. `cheur` => `chfeur` and `, date)` => `, date ))`).